# Wxpython Listctrl

Tags: wxpython

Please run the below code and here i have a button addscript in one frame ,
onbutton click opens an other frame which consists of combobox of data as displayed.after selecting appropriate choice and click updateandclose button those values in combobox should be printed on the listctrl which is on other frame

cananyone help me out with this

Thanks in advance

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial",size=(700, 400))

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,200),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Machine Name')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Sim Port')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Sim Script', width=125)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, 'Status', width=150)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(4, 'Status Detail', width=300)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        btn2 = wx.Button(panel,label = "Add Script")
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_script)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn2,0,wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        menu = wx.Menu()
        #exit = menu.Append(-1, "Exit")
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exit)
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        #wx.StaticText(self.m_panel1, -1,(25,25))
        self.popupmenu = wx.Menu()
        for text in "Start Stop Remove".split():
            item = self.popupmenu.Append(-1, text)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPopupItemSelected, item)
            self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.ShowPopUp)

        #self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.ShowPopUp)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def add_script(self, event):
        # mp is item 2
        self.new = NewWindow(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()

    def add_line(self, event):
        #line = "Line %s" % self.index
        line = 'LDR2'
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index,line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "22000")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "LF1-trk")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 3, "running")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 4, "last Status info received")
        self.index += 1

    def OnPopupItemSelected(self, event):
        item = self.popupmenu.FindItemById(event.GetId())
        text = item.GetText()
        wx.MessageBox("You selected item '%s'" % text)

    def ShowPopUp( self, event ):
        #pos = self.list_ctrl.GetPosition()
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        pos = self.list_ctrl.ScreenToClient(pos)
        self.list_ctrl.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu,pos)
        event.Skip()

class NewWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'New Window', size=(400,300))
        #self.frame1 = MainWindow;

        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Machine")
        sizer.Add(text1, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        comboBox1Choices = [ u"LDR2", u"AT02" ]
       # self.m_comboBox4 = wx.ComboBox( panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Running", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_comboBoxChoices, 0 )
        self.comboBox1 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox1Choices, 0 )
        #comboBox1.SetSelection(1)
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox1, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Sim Port")
        sizer.Add(text2, pos=(3, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        comboBox2Choices = [ u"22000", u"23000" ]
        self.comboBox2 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox2Choices, 0 )
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox2, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        text3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Sim Scripts")
        sizer.Add(text3, pos=(4, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, border=10)

        comboBox3Choices = [ u"LF12-Ldr", u"LF1-Trk",u"CN1-Trk" ]
        self.comboBox3 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox3Choices, 0 )
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox3, pos=(4, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        text4 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Status")
        sizer.Add(text4, pos=(5, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, border=10)

        comboBox4Choices = [ u"Not Started", u"Running" ]
        self.comboBox4 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox4Choices, 0 )
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox4, pos=(5, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        self.button4 = wx.Button(panel, label="Update and Close")
        sizer.Add(self.button4, pos=(7, 3))

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(2)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.button4.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onupdateandClose)

    def onupdateandClose(self,event):

       # self.index = 0
        self.main = MyForm()
        sc = self.comboBox1.GetSelection()
        print sc
        sd = self.comboBox1.GetString(sc)
        print sd
        #sa = self.main.m_staticText5.SetLabel(self.comboBox1.GetString(sc))
        #sa = self.frame1.m_staticText4.SetLabel(self.comboBox1.GetString(sc))
        #print sa
        cb1 = self.comboBox1.GetValue()
        #print sc
        cb2 = self.comboBox2.GetValue()
        cb3 = self.comboBox3.GetValue()
        cb4 = self.comboBox4.GetValue()
        #num_items = self.main.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()
        #print num_items
        num_items = 0

        #line = "Line %s" % self.index
        #print line
        line = 'LDR2'

        self.main.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(num_items,line)
        self.main.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(num_items, 1, 'gjg')
        self.main.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(num_items, 2, str(cb2))
        num_items += 1
        self.Close()


    def test(self, event):
        self.new = NewWindow(parent=None, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't want to change your code. I added only codes.

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "List Control Tutorial",size=(700, 400))

        # Add a panel so it looks the correct on all platforms
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        self.index = 0

        self.list_ctrl = wx.ListCtrl(panel, size=(-1,200),
                         style=wx.LC_REPORT
                         |wx.BORDER_SUNKEN
                         )
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(0, 'Machine Name')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(1, 'Sim Port')
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(2, 'Sim Script', width=125)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(3, 'Status', width=150)
        self.list_ctrl.InsertColumn(4, 'Status Detail', width=300)

        btn = wx.Button(panel, label="Add Line")
        btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_line)

        btn2 = wx.Button(panel,label = "Add Script")
        btn2.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.add_script)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.list_ctrl, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn2,0,wx.ALL|wx.CENTER, 5)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        menu = wx.Menu()
        #exit = menu.Append(-1, "Exit")
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, exit)
        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        #wx.StaticText(self.m_panel1, -1,(25,25))
        self.popupmenu = wx.Menu()
        for text in "Start Stop Remove".split():
            item = self.popupmenu.Append(-1, text)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnPopupItemSelected, item)
            self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_CONTEXT_MENU, self.ShowPopUp)

        #self.list_ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_LIST_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.ShowPopUp)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def add_script(self, event):
        # mp is item 2
        self.new = NewWindow(self, id=-1)
        self.new.Show()

    def add_line(self, event):
        #line = "Line %s" % self.index
        line = 'LDR2'
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index,line)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, "22000")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, "LF1-trk")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 3, "running")
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 4, "last Status info received")
        self.index += 1

    def add_line_dynamic(self, machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status):
        print machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, machine_name)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, sim_port)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, sim_script)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 3, status)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 4, "none")
        self.index += 1

    def OnPopupItemSelected(self, event):
        item = self.popupmenu.FindItemById(event.GetId())
        text = item.GetText()
        wx.MessageBox("You selected item '%s'" % text)

    def ShowPopUp( self, event ):
        #pos = self.list_ctrl.GetPosition()
        pos = event.GetPosition()
        pos = self.list_ctrl.ScreenToClient(pos)
        self.list_ctrl.PopupMenu(self.popupmenu,pos)
        event.Skip()

class NewWindow(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'New Window', size=(400,300))
        #self.frame1 = MainWindow;
        self.parent = parent

        wx.Frame.CenterOnScreen(self)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5, 5)

        text1 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Machine")
        sizer.Add(text1, pos=(2, 0), flag=wx.LEFT, border=10)

        comboBox1Choices = [ u"LDR2", u"AT02" ]
       # self.m_comboBox4 = wx.ComboBox( panel, wx.ID_ANY, u"Running", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, m_comboBoxChoices, 0 )
        self.comboBox1 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox1Choices, 0 )
        #comboBox1.SetSelection(1)
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox1, pos=(2, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        text2 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Sim Port")
        sizer.Add(text2, pos=(3, 0), flag=wx.LEFT|wx.TOP, border=10)

        comboBox2Choices = [ u"22000", u"23000" ]
        self.comboBox2 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox2Choices, 0 )
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox2, pos=(3, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        text3 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Sim Scripts")
        sizer.Add(text3, pos=(4, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, border=10)

        comboBox3Choices = [ u"LF12-Ldr", u"LF1-Trk",u"CN1-Trk" ]
        self.comboBox3 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox3Choices, 0 )
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox3, pos=(4, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        text4 = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Status")
        sizer.Add(text4, pos=(5, 0), flag=wx.TOP|wx.LEFT, border=10)

        comboBox4Choices = [ u"Not Started", u"Running" ]
        self.comboBox4 = wx.ComboBox(panel,wx.ID_ANY,u"", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, comboBox4Choices, 0 )
        sizer.Add( self.comboBox4, pos=(5, 1), span=(1, 3), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND )

        self.button4 = wx.Button(panel, label="Update and Close")
        sizer.Add(self.button4, pos=(7, 3))

        sizer.AddGrowableCol(2)

        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        self.button4.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON,self.onupdateandClose)

    def onupdateandClose(self,event):

       # self.index = 0
        self.main = MyForm()
        sc = self.comboBox1.GetSelection()
        machine_name = self.comboBox1.GetString(sc)
        #sa = self.main.m_staticText5.SetLabel(self.comboBox1.GetString(sc))
        #sa = self.frame1.m_staticText4.SetLabel(self.comboBox1.GetString(sc))
        #print sa
        machine_name = self.comboBox1.GetValue()
        #print sc
        sim_port = self.comboBox2.GetValue()
        sim_script = self.comboBox3.GetValue()
        status = self.comboBox4.GetValue()
        #num_items = self.main.list_ctrl.GetItemCount()
        #print num_items
        num_items = 0

        #line = "Line %s" % self.index
        #print line
        # line = 'LDR2'

        # self.main.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(num_items,line)
        # self.main.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(num_items, 1, 'gjg')
        # self.main.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(num_items, 2, str(cb2))
        # num_items += 1

        self.parent.add_line_dynamic(machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status)
        self.Close()


    # def test(self, event):
    #     self.new = NewWindow(parent=None, id=-1)
    #     self.new.Show()
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Run the program
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I added a function in the class MyForm, *named add_line_dynamic(machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status)*.

```
def add_line_dynamic(self, machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status):
        print machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status
        self.list_ctrl.InsertStringItem(self.index, machine_name)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 1, sim_port)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 2, sim_script)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 3, status)
        self.list_ctrl.SetStringItem(self.index, 4, "none")
        self.index += 1
```

This function will be called from the other class NewWindow().
The call is doing with parent.
*self.parent.add_line_dynamic(machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status).*

```
self.parent.add_line_dynamic(machine_name, sim_port, sim_script, status)
```

NewWindow is called from MyForm. And NewWindow knows his parent Myform. And you can call another function from his parent and transfer arguments to the class.
I hope you understand the logic.

p.s. sorry for my english :)